# PDO fetch() error

Tags: pdo, fetch

Here's my code:

```
    $qer="insert into users (user,first,last,bio,email,pass,date,bd) values ('$name','$first','$last','$bio','$email','$pass','$date','$bd')";
$query=$con->query("select * from 'users'");
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['user'];
}
```

And here's my error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/it/newuser.php on line 97
```

Line 97 is the while statement, of course.

I'm not sure why it thinks it's not handling an object... or why I think it is. Help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `users` should not be single quoted.  `select * from users`.  Single quotes identify string literals, not column names.

Comment: Note that although we don't see what you ultimately do with that `insert` statement, you are getting _none_ of the benefits PDO offers since you are placing variables directly into it.  Please consider converting it to a prepared statement with placeholders.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, if I use double quotes, it cuts off my $qer definition. Also, I will use prepared statements and whatnot once I get my queries working.

Comment: The whole select statement should be quoted, but _not_ `users` the column name

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I am silly. Thanks.